# OpenShift add cartridge MySQL 5.5 engine InnoDB

Tags: mysql, database, openshift, innodb

when i do

```
 rhc cartridge add mysql-5.5 --app NameApp
```

the engine **default** of DB is **MyISAM**. But if i need engine **InnoDB**, how can i create db on OpenShift?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default storage engine for mysql is set with an environment variable. Add the cartridge, then run the below to use InnoDB:

```
$ rhc env add OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DEFAULT_STORAGE_ENGINE=InnoDB -a NameApp
$ rhc app-restart NameApp
```

See the mysql cartridge configuration where this is set:

https://github.com/openshift/origin-server/blob/master/cartridges/openshift-origin-cartridge-mysql/conf/my.cnf.erb#L39